# System.currentTimeMillis() выдает неправильный результат

Tags: java

Доброго времени суток!

`System.currentTimeMillis()` в *Java* выдает неправильный результат.

То есть по логам выдает `1569633070510`,что не является действительностью. 
Но, если отсечь три последние цифры `(510)`,то результат становится достоверным.

Подскажите,пожалуйста,откуда он берет эти лишние цифры и как можно убрать их?

Comment: используй `System.nanoTime();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это и есть миллисекунды. Только Вы их перепутали с секундами.

```
1569633070510 / 1000 / 3600 / 24 / 365.25 = 49.74 (почти 50 лет с 1-го января 1970 года)
```

Comment: Точно,тупанул и не разделил на 1000,спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Используйте класс `java.sql.Date`:

```
Date currentDate = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
```

переведет в текущую дату - все ровно должно быть..